# Displaying a scala option field in html typescript using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, scala

I am trying to display a scala option field in my UI:

```
div class="main" *ngIf="document && document.source">
    <p-accordion [multiple]="true" expandIcon="qe-icon-chevron-right" collapseIcon="qe-icon-chevron-down">
        <p-accordionTab [header]="headerAttribute" [selected]="true">
            <dl class="ui-g">
                <ng-container *ngIf="document.source.optionField">
                    <dt class="ui-g-4">Option Field:</dt>
                    <dd class="ui-g-8" [innerHTML]="document.source.optionField|keepHtml"></dd>
                </ng-container>
            </dl>
        </p-accordionTab>
    </p-accordion>
</div>
```

Currently when displayed UI end it is shown as Some() instead of .

Is there a way of correcting this at the HTML level either by using angular pipes or other methods? Or do I need to go back and correct my case class so the HTML field is no longer an option value.

Comment: Could you detail how you are rendering the html from scala? With a library? You are manually writing a string and returning to the http client? What's the output of that? Did you get an error? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)